# Liferay Portal 6.1 EE - DLUtil.getPreviewURL

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

We create a pdf-download URL in our Liferay Portal 6.1 EE via following
method call:

```
String fileUrl = DLUtil.getPreviewURL(file, fileVersion, null, StringPool.BLANK, false, true);
```

Is it possible to remove the generated "number-letter-combination" (bold text) from the link or place it at a certain point in the url ?

documents/10180/1423151/AT0000753173_FAT.pdf/**461a1fdf-6e61-4cb3-8c1d-77cb527e3609**

Thanks a lot for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

the "number-letter-combination"  is the file uuid field and there is no way to move that calling the method DLUtil.getPreviewURL. But you can build  the url yourself in this way

```
    StringBundler sb = new StringBundler();
    sb.append(PortalUtil.getPathContext());
    sb.append("/documents/");
    sb.append(fileEntry.getRepositoryId());
    sb.append(StringPool.SLASH);
    sb.append(fileEntry.getFolderId());
    sb.append(StringPool.SLASH);
    sb.append(HttpUtil.encodeURL(HtmlUtil.unescape(fileEntry.getTitle())));
    fileUrl = sb.toString()
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for your help. Will try it immediately.